# NG-SELECT disabled not working with directive using angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, angular12, angular-ngselect

I am trying to disable ng-select through directive. Can anyone suggest How can I do this?

This is my code and here is the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-update-from-directive-8wdi66?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fcurrency-select.directive.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). which was I trying.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const selectElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.tagName === 'NG-SELECT') {
    console.log('selectElement :', this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    this.renderer.setProperty(selectElement, 'disabled', true);
    this.renderer.setProperty(selectElement, ' ng-select-disabled', '');
    this.renderer.addClass(selectElement, 'disabled');
    const inputEle = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    this.renderer.setProperty(inputEle, 'disabled', true);
  }
}, 1000);
```

I tried many ways But I need to do this with directives Can anyone know how can i do this with directive?

- [disabled]="true" => working with ngModel
- [readonly]="true" => working with formControlName
- But not working with directive.

Can anyone suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-update-from-directive-qsfynr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fcurrency-select.directive.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

just retrieve the host component from the constructor, so here `NgSelectComponent` and use the method `setDisabledState`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { NgSelectComponent } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCurrencySelect]',
})
export class CurrencySelectDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private el: NgSelectComponent) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const selectElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
      if (selectElement.nativeElement.tagName === 'NG-SELECT') {
        this.el.setDisabledState(true);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's working with angular 16 but not working with angular 12. In my angular 12. my angular version : `12.2.0` and ng-select version is =>  `"@ng-select/ng-select": "^7.3.0"`.